# Pandas value_count set the interval manually rather than equal intervals

Tags: python, pandas

A simple example:

```
d=pd.DataFrame({'x':np.arange(100)})   
d.x.value_counts(normalize=True,bins=5)
```

Then I get:

```
Out[61]: 
(79.2, 99.0]    0.2
(59.4, 79.2]    0.2
(39.6, 59.4]    0.2
(19.8, 39.6]    0.2
(-0.1, 19.8]    0.2
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

Can I set the intervals by myself. For example I want to get the frequency of

```
(0,23],(23,50],(50,100]
```

The intervals' range may not be equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass you own `bins` with `value_counts`

```
d.x.value_counts(bins=[0,23,50,100])
Out[197]: 
(50.0, 100.0]     49
(23.0, 50.0]      27
(-0.001, 23.0]    24
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks. It helps a lot. There is no any description about this usage in the official document...